# How does `std::string::find_last_of()` actually work?

Tags: c++, string

```
string s = "I Like C++ Tutorial";
cout << s.find_last_of("Like");
```

I know that find_last_of returns the last character that matches, however, it returns `16`, which is the position of the letter `i` in `Tutorial`, But I'm confused because I'm searching for the last position of `Like` not `i`, I tried to remove `i` from the string. It returns `5` as I expected. But the question is why did it return `16`?

Comment: read the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) to see why `find_last_of` behaves that way, you want [`rfind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) if you want to match a substring in a string from the end

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`find_last_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) finds the last character equal to one of characters in the given character sequence.

The character sequence is `"Like"`. The last `L` is at position `3`, the last `i` is at position `16`, the last `k` is at position `4` and the the last `e` is at position `5`. So it returned the `16`, the greatest of these values.

If the character sequence was `"like"` instead of `"Like"`, it would have returned `18` because the last `l` is at position `18`.

In case no letter in the character sequence that matches any letter in the string, [`npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) is returned.

Comment: Might want to note what it does in the case an element is not found, e.g. searching for "Likes" finds no 's'

Comment: Is it true that npos is -1 ? can I consider it so ?

Comment: @Jackt it is definitionally `static const size_type npos = -1;`, but `-1` on it's own is of type `int`, not `std::string::size_type`

Answer (score 3):

[std::find_last_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of)

> Finds the last character equal to one of characters in str

this means when searching the string "I Like C++ Tutorial" for the string "Like" the last character that apears in both strings is "i" wich is at position 16.

when searching for a complete string use [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

```
std::string s("I Like C++ Tutorial");
std::cout << s.find("Like"); // prints 2
```

if you want to find the last occurence of the string use [std::rfind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind)

```
std::string s("I Like C++ Tutorial Like");
std::cout << s.rfind("Like"); // prints 20
```

to get the position of the last character in the last match you just have to add the length of the string:

```
std::string s("I Like C++ Tutorial Like");
std::string s2("Like");
std::cout << s.rfind(s2) + s2.length(); // prints 24
```